# FactoryGirl not finding instances in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot, minitest

When attempting to initialize data with FactoryGirl I am running into a problem with being able to access previous data I have created.

Say I have 3 different Models: Product, CartItem, and OrderItem. And these are the basic rules:

- CartItem and OrderItem belong_to Product, and is required.
- Product has a unique identifier 'name'.

My Factory files are set up like so:

**Product**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name "A Product"
  end
end
```

**CartItem**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cart_item do
    association :product do
        Product.find_by(name: "A Product") || FactoryGirl.create(:product)
    end
  end
end
```

**OrderItem**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order_item do
    association :product do
        Product.find_by(name: "A Product") || FactoryGirl.create(:product)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, within one test, I first create CartItem using this call `FactoryGirl.create(:cart_item)`

Everything runs fine. Because there is no Product, it creates a new one and then assigns it to CartItem.

Next, I then attempt to create OrderItem using this call `FactoryGirl.create(:order_item)`

This time when I run it, it fails with the error `Validation failed, Name has already been taken`

This fails when trying to create a new Product with the name "A Product", which was already created from the call to create CartItem.

However, this should never even attempt to create a new Product instance because I set the OrderItem's product using this `Product.find_by("A Product") || FactoryGirl.create(:product)` which should first attempt to find that product instance before creating a new one.

Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Ive also tried doing this `unless Product.find_by(name: "A Product") do FactoryGirl.create(:product) end` and the same issue occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

I believe your issue is with the way you're using `association`. I don't see anywhere that association takes a block the way you're defining it.

What you want to do instead is something like this

```
factory :cart_item do
  product { Product.find_by(name: "A Product") || association(:product) }       
end
```

This actually seems wrong since you're creating non-determinism. Instead, you should create a record and assign it directly to the factory in your tests.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cart_item do
    association :product 
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order_item do
    association :product
  end
end
```

Then in your tests

```
product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
cart_item = FactoryGirl.create(:cart_item, product: product)
order_item = FactoryGirl.create(:order_item, product: product)
```

Comment: My bad, that was a typo error. my code is actually doing `Product.find_by(name: "A Product")` I just fixed that in my original question. But with the 'name' declaration in there it is still having the same problem

Comment: Actually, where did you find that syntax for `association` on FactoryGirl. I don't think `association` takes a block...or at least it is not documented

Comment: I honestly just tried it based off of how Ruby generally works, and it worked. I needed a way to associate a Model with a User using Devise, but you can't create a user utilizing devise by simply doing `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`. Instead you have to go `@user_attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)` followed by 'User.create(@user_attr)'. Since the association call wasn't coming from a factory, I replaced it with a `do` statement and placed those two calls in it. It works.

Comment: And since it worked with User, I figured it would have to work for others

Comment: I'm not following your previous comments as they don't really follow what you're doing?

Comment: Your first example is working properly, except I changed it to `product { Product.first || FactoryGirl.create(:product) }` This works best for what I will be doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but try commenting out FactoryGirl.lint in your FactoryGirl config.